# CMake: How to import a 'module' into a project?

Tags: import, cmake, module

Here is my setup:

```
/CoolProject
    main.c
    CMakeLists.txt

/MyLib
    foo.c
    CMakeLists.txt
```

Here is what I have for the CMakeLists.txt in CoolProject

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.4)

project(CoolProject)

add_executable(CoolProject main.c)

target_link_libraries(CoolProject MyLib)
```

Here is what I have for the CMakeLists.txt in MyLib

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.4)

add_library(MyLib STATIC foo.c)
```

How do I configure CoolProject's CMakeLists.txt to find MyLib and to build it?

Answer (score -1):

I found the answer in the [CMake Examples](http://www.cmake.org/examples/)